# Opengl Es 2.0 Shader Manager

Tags: performance, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

i have a simple question, is it faster to check integer value from memory or ask opengl to do something simple, like use program, or bind texture?
I am writing shader manager class and just wondering is there any diffrence, from my point of view it looks like its cheaper to check integer to avoid not needed calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding unnecessary pipeline state changes is always a good thing and I can imagine that checking integer value will be cheaper than making a glUseProgram call. It is just necessary to be "program coherent" while rendering, so you dont do both (check and glUseProgram) most of the time. I also recomend you to read this guide http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH1-SW1. It will help you with optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

one of the best method to optimize the code is to avoid as many OpenGL/DX function calls as possible. So for most of the time checking only one local variable should be better than using openGL code.

sometimes OpenGL will sync with the CPU to perform some code: like glGetTexImage, getPixels, etc... and this will hurt performance a lot.

when comes to 'use programs' or 'bind texture' I do not know exactly what is the cost. It depends on the spec and device implementation.